Funny 70s-80s Army movie with comic scenes involving Laundry and a Flag
I am searching for a movie I watched long ago on StarMovies. It was aired in the 90s on StarMovies India. It was rated 18+
It was about 3-4 friends in the army training camp and about their adventures.
It was a British/American movie in colour and in English. I was quite young when I saw it. The characters(4 friends mentioned above) were all white, blonde, young and clean shaven. One of the character's name was Jerry.
One of the scenes I recollect is :
Where in they had painted their uniforms but soon their senior finds out about it and asks them to wash. Wherein they promptly obey the
orders but they end up hanging their clothes on a rope - which later on turns out to be a rope where the flag is being hoisted and the flag hoisting
becomes a funny exhibition of their nearly-still-dirty clothes.
Another scene is where they are demonstrating to civilians about life-saving techniques and they are accompanied by female nurses. But their excitement
turns into a tragedy:
First volunteer is asked to remove pants and civilians are asked to try out giving injections to patients while the second one expecting a mouth-to-mouth from a beautiful nurse gets the same but by an elderly senior female nurse!
Another scene is when the Sergent comes to inspect their food bowls. One of the 4 friends has thrown his bowl away. They are sitting at 2 tables with 2 on each table and the Sergent is standing in the middle to inspect the bowls. To avoid detection by the Sergent they pass 1 bowl from the opposite table when he looks at one of the tables. When he sees 2 on a table he sees that have 2 bowls and when he turns he finds that the other table has 2 bowls as well. But there are just 3 bowls in all in the scene.
This movie has other funny scenes too...but I don't remember name of this movie...

Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

@Paulie_D I have updated the question with the origin and language of the movie. A couple of scenes are already described in the question.

added further details and another scene
